# FFMPEG take 3 minutes to generate thumbanils

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, ffprobe, fluent-ffmpeg

I am generating the sprite image (combined thumbnails/screenshots) using FLUENT-FFMPEG and node js, the image looks like this.

[image]

Here is my node js script for generating sprite images/thumbnails.

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpegCommand = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpegCommand.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

let videoUrl =
  "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4";
const filename = `output_image`;

ffmpegCommand(videoUrl)
  .seekInput("00:00:01.000")
  .outputOptions([
    "-q:v",
    "8",
    "-frames:v",
    "1",
    "-vsync",
    "0",
    "-qscale",
    "50",
    "-vf",
    "fps=1/10,scale=128:72,tile=11x11",
  ])
  .addOption("-preset", "superfast")
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("error", err);
    reject(err);
  })

  .save(`./tmp/${filename}.png`);
```

**Unfortunately, it takes almost 3 minutes to generate this image which is so bad.**

**UPDATE**

@kesh answer is working only with internal videos.

if I add the video URL as follows.

`let videoUrl ="./videos/t.mp4";`

then it takes less than 3 seconds to generate thumbnails.

but if I use an external URL as follows.

`let videoUrl ="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4";`

Weird, it takes too long to generate thumbnails more than 3 minutes depending on the video.

**NOTE** you can read full documentation [here](https://fluent-ffmpeg.github.io/)  about FFmpeg and node js.

What do I need to change so that I can super fast generate my thumbnails?

Comment: how big file it is ? i think its taking more time because of download time.
also why did you go with a library instead of using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) directly.

Comment: @bogdanoff where did I use the child process? or can you show your solution via code?

Comment: `fluent-ffmpeg` all it does is invokes subprocess of ffmpeg in fancy way and in this case you can directly invoke subprocess instead of using this package. I can share snippet for this but I doubt it won't solve your problem, since your main problem is download latency not with ffmpeg itself. 
so let me know if you still want snippet.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Use the `-discard nokey` input option

It takes so long because it's decoding all the video frames to cover 1210 seconds (~2 minutes of the content). ...well, I don't know exactly why your setup takes 3 minutes tho...

Anyway, starting with the `fps` filter is good to reduce the filtering load (scaling is only performed on the frames that you want to include) but it doesn't prevent all the frames to be decoded, only For the most of them to be thrown out (keeping only 1 out of 240).

One way (only way?) to prevent decoder to process all the frames is to tell it to ignore non-keyframes. The keyframe interval should be tight enough you'd still get the desired effect.

I've tested it with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -discard nokey -i "{inurl}" \
       -vf fps=1/10,scale=128:72,tile=11x11 \
       -an -frames:v 1 {outurl}
```

My (~10-years-old) PC took 36.3s without `-discard nokey` while it took only 2.7s with the option. (tested in Python)

Comment: in the command line it's all good can you provide your solution using node js as I tried? I tried but not getting the results I want

Comment: Nope, I don't daily drive node.js to be able to test it. If your 3-minute solution is producing the results you need but very slowly, I'd add `-discard nokey` to the input option (donno how, maybe as an argument to `ffmpegCommand` or is there `inputOptions()`?). Assuming it's running the same FFmpeg version as your cli setup, you should get the identical results.

Comment: yes there is inpuToptions let me try again.

Comment: Now when I use an external URL it takes too long, is there any solution to make this faster even for external urls?

Comment: Here is https://i.stack.imgur.com/rROF3.png

Comment: That must be the downloading latency. Get a faster network connection would be best I can tell ya. Or cache the target ahead of time if known.

Comment: what do you mean cache the target ahead of time ?

Comment: Instead of letting FFmpeg to download the file (place it in a temp dir), download it from node.js then call FFmpeg. This will help if the bottleneck is FFmpeg's html protocol. If not, then the problem is simply the slow connection between your device and the mp4's host, and not much you can do about it. Oh one other thing you can try: just do `ffmpeg -i inurl -c copy out.mp4` and see how long it takes.

Comment: that command also took long time to finish

Comment: Now try something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-a-file-using-node-js/)

Comment: it download but it takes too long , I think I need to find a way to generate thumbnails without downloading the file

Comment: hi, kesh did you get time to find the solution? I am still struggling with a remote video url